# Why target="blank" attribute doesn't work in this case?

Tags: hyperlink

I have a Home page with links to Offer page and Contact page, which are different `.html` files, and a Home page, which is current file.
First two have attributes: `target="blank"`, and `rel="noopener noreferrer"`.

When i click on one of those links, it correctly opens new page in a new tab.

But when i come back to Home page using Home link and then i try to open one of the two first links, the attribute `target="blank"` doesn't work anymore and I'm getting redirected to chosen page, instead of opening it in a new tab.

Can anyone explain what is happening? Can i change this behavior?

Comment: Use `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Wow, worked like a charm. Thanks!